# Self-gravitating light

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity

In

[The gravitational field of a laser beam beyond the short wavelength approximation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324745027_The_gravitational_field_of_a_laser_beam_beyond_the_short_wavelength_approximation) (Fabienne Schneiter, Dennis Rätzel, Daniel Braun)

and previous work it is shown that under certain conditions „light does not gravitate“.

Unfortunately all results are derived in linearised gravity.

Question: are there any results for strong electromagnetic fields and strong curvature?

Comment: I thought the Bonnor beam was an exact solution?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks a lot. (However the Bonnor beam seems to be not a laser beam or pulse but an infinite tube of null dust)